# TypeError: <flask_script.commands.Command object at >: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments

Tags: python, flask

I'm working through https://realpython.com/blog/python/handling-email-confirmation-in-flask/#flask-basic-registration to build an email registration system. (https://github.com/mjhea0/flask-basic-registration)

In the models.py there is:

```
class User(db.Model):

__tablename__ = "users"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

def __init__(self, email, password, registered_on, admin=False, confirmed=False, confirmed_on=None):
    self.email = email
    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
    self.registered_on = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.admin = admin
    self.confirmed = confirmed
    self.confirmed_on = confirmed_on
     .....
```

In manage.py I can run a management function that looks like:

```
@manager.command
def create_admin():
    """Creates the admin user."""
    db.session.add(User(
        email="ad@min.com",
        password="admin",
        admin=True,
        confirmed=True,
        confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now())
    )
    db.session.commit()
```

When I do I get:

```
$ python manage.py create_admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 78, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_script\__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_script\__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "c:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_script\commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "manage.py", line 30, in create_admin
    confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now())
TypeError: <flask_script.commands.Command object at 0x03530410>: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (6 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python there are 2 types of arguments. Positional arguments defined like this:

```
def function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
```

and keyword arguments defined like this:

```
def function(arg1="arg1 value", arg2="arg2 value"):
```

All positional arguments are always required, and keyword arguments are optional (they will take the value given to them in the definition by default if you don't explicitly give them to the function). You are trying to call positional arguments as keyword arguments. You are also failing to give the required `registered_on` positional argument. If you take out the keywords in `create_admin` and add the positional `registered_on` argument to make it look like this it should run:

```
@manager.command
def create_admin():
    """Creates the admin user."""
    db.session.add(User(
        "ad@min.com",
        "admin",
        datetime.datetime.now() # this is the registered_on argument
        admin=True,
        confirmed=True,
        confirmed_on=datetime.datetime.now())
    )
    db.session.commit()
```

If you want to change the definition rather than the call you could do this instead:

```
class User(db.Model):

__tablename__ = "users"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True)

def __init__(self, email="user@host", password="password", registered_on=datetime.datetime.now(), admin=False, confirmed=False, confirmed_on=None):
    self.email = email
    self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
    self.registered_on = registered_on
    self.admin = admin
    self.confirmed = confirmed
    self.confirmed_on = confirmed_on
     .....
```

Or you could do some combination of the above, keeping in mind what I said about positional and keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks Danny, I'm just suprised because if you look at https://realpython.com/blog/python/handling-email-confirmation-in-flask/#update-the-current-app he's giving some variables value but not others - def __init__(self, email, password, confirmed,
                 paid=False, admin=False, confirmed_on=None):

Comment: @user61629 you can have method signatures that use both positional and keyword arguments. Just the positional ones will be required, and the keyword args will have default values if they are not passed.